# jQuery wait for event to complete

Tags: jquery

How can I realize that when I have a function

```
$('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000);
```

that the program exetutes the function test() after the slideToggle completed?

If I write like this:

```
$('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000);
test();
```

...test() gets executed before slideToggle completed.

How can I realize? I don't know jQuery very well ...

Thank you for your help! Regards, Florian

EDIT: Results u can see here: [www.virtual-swiss-hornets.ch](http://virtual-swiss-hornets.ch)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a [callback](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) function to your jQuery function.

```
$('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000,function() { test(); });
```

That function will ONLY fire once the slide is complete.

Answer (score 4):

I think `slideToggle` should accept the second argument `callback`, like this:

```
$('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000, function() {/* do anything after animation is complete */});
```

Actually for your particular case it is as easy as:

```
$('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000, test);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this to fire **once**, Checkout the jquery API for [when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

```
$.when(('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000)).done(function() { test(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use the callback function

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

.slideToggle( [ duration ], [ callback ] )

```
   ('.anyclass').slideToggle(1000, function() { test(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be this

`$('#result').append($("<div class='message'>Result Sucess</div>")).slideToggle(5000,function(){$(this).remove()});`